# import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;

Tags: java, apache, jar

I am getting error "Can not be resolved to a type" for the statement

`import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;`

Which jar file, I need to add in buildpath to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

This class is from [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) (`commons-net-<VERSION>.jar`)

I guess you should download the latest version (3.2)

Comment: Yes, i downloaded latest version commons-net-3.2.jar, commons-net-3.2-sources.jar, commons-net-examples-3.2.jar. still i am facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

this belongs to Apache commons-net.jar

Comment: Yes, i downloaded latest version commons-net-3.2.jar, commons-net-3.2-sources.jar, commons-net-examples-3.2.jar and added all these three in build path. still i am facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Apache Commons Net API, to your build path. [More Info](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.2/index.html)

Comment: ok,how can we add that Apache Commons Net API to build path? Can we need to down load any jar file for that?

Comment: @Manivasu, if you are using eclipse go to Project Properties -> Build Path and then add External Jar file there, after downloading Apache Commons Net api jar file

Comment: Yes, i down loaded commons-net-3.2-bin.zip. In this we found 3 jar files, commons-net-3.2, commons-net-3.2-sources and  commons-net-examples-3.2. Then i added all these 3 jar files into project build path. Still it could not get resolved.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and re-building your project?

Comment: Yes, i did clean and build after adding these 3 jar files.

Answer (score 0):

The class is present in Apache commons-net.jar. [Download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/apache-commons/apache-commons-net.jar.zip)
You need to add this to your classpath